# How to show 5 levels of deep navigation on the LHS navigation

Tags: navigation

I am trying to come up with a better deep nav system that can have as much as 5 levels of deep navigation on the LHS nav.. I thought of something like attached.. what do you guys think?[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess something is wrong with your Information Architecture

To make it easier to navigate

- **Use context based left Nav with max 3 levels of depth**
- **Use a Horizontal Nav along with Left Nav, it will cover 2 levels**

Use Horizontal top navigation for major categories and sub categories and then use Left Nav to further drill down